# Create dynamic pagination for div block in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have created a table using div instead of using table structure.Now I want to add pagination feature for this table which is created using div's.
I wanted to know whether there is any plugin available which works with div.

Here is sample code

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-swipe">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-0">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <span class="row1 date-content date whitespace">Col1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-0">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <span class="row1 date-content date">Col2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 hidden-xs hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <a class="id">Col3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this sample code repeated.I have created table using the above structure.How can I now add pagination to this,Or how can I convert this into table so as to use pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore [JQuery Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/). client-side or server-side pagination possible. Including infinite scroll.

Comment: For using datatables you need to have table rows which is missing in my structure

Comment: what you intend to display in these 3 columns? Can you provide a sample dataset

Comment: These three columns are used to display Name,phone number and email address.I'm using angular-js ng-repeat to dynamically fill the div

Comment: and you will be querying this data from server? using AJAX call?

Comment: you can still use datatables. here is a simple ajax example https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html . you can find more complex ajax examples here https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html

Comment: I know i can use datatables but for that i need to change my exisiting div structure to table format.Datatables works on div element? i'm not sure about that.

Comment: No. Tabular data should use the TABLE tag, while a DIV is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSONPagination Plugin](https://github.com/dheeraja00/JSONPagination), which doesn't depend on the DOM, since its done in the JSON level so you can create any kind of table using div or table tag, only few steps needs to be remembered which is explained in the plugin itself.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin.